# Unexpected MYSQl error 1286

Tags: database

I am using shared host and after some problems they restarted the server and my Drupal website shows the following error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1286 Unknown table engine 'InnoDB': SELECT
```

This is the full log

Error message

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1286
>   Unknown table engine 'InnoDB': SELECT
>   field_data_media_gallery_expose_block0.entity_type AS entity_type,
>   field_data_media_gallery_expose_block0.entity_id AS entity_id,
>   field_data_media_gallery_expose_block0.revision_id AS revision_id,
>   field_data_media_gallery_expose_block0.bundle AS bundle FROM
>   {field_data_media_gallery_expose_block}
>   field_data_media_gallery_expose_block0 WHERE
>   (field_data_media_gallery_expose_block0.media_gallery_expose_block_value
>   = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (field_data_media_gallery_expose_block0.deleted =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_1) AND
>   (field_data_media_gallery_expose_block0.entity_type =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_2) AND
>   (field_data_media_gallery_expose_block0.bundle =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_3) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0]
>   => 1 [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => 0 [:db_condition_placeholder_2] => node [:db_condition_placeholder_3] => media_gallery ) in field_sql_storage_field_storage_query() (line 577 of
>   /home/fossisor/public_html/techiestuffs/modules/field/modules/field_sql_storage/field_sql_storage.module).

What is wrong with the database ?

Comment: A quick google gives this link, which gives some more insight: http://www.youdidwhatwithtsql.com/unknown-table-engine-innodb/760

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your hosting provider does not support InnoDB. There are a few others like you, here is a discussion thread with some ideas on how to fix it http://drupal.org/node/1089724

Comment: but My other drupal sites in same host works great

Comment: Have you checked your other sites since the server restart?